# Knuths arrow notation

Tags: functions

I have looked at Knuth's arrow notation and am wondering if multiplication can be represented by $n\uparrow^0m$.
Also whether addition can be represented as $n\uparrow^{-1}m$.

Comment: I know from no other purpose of this notation other than generating huge numbers. But there is a hyperoperator-definition indeed convering also addition and multiplication.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation, we have the following facts:

- $a\uparrow^nb=H_{n+2}(a,b)$
- $H_1(a,b)=a+b$
- $H_2(a,b)=a\times b$

Knuth's arrow notation is usually considered for $n\geq 1$, but we can extend it to $n\geq-2$ to have the identities,

- $a\uparrow^{-1}b=H_1(a,b)=a+b$
- $a\uparrow^0b=H_2(a,b)=a\times b$